# How do I change animated values for multiple keyframes?

Tags: animation, modifiers, camera

In Blender 2.82 I have lots of keyframes for a camera that I want to change position to altogether at once, how can I do that? The local animation is correct, but the whole location for all of it needs to be changed, like add 2000m for all in Z axis, add X, Y...
If not possible in Blender, can it be done in AE? It's over 700 frames so nothing I want to do manually :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how much it will help you, but you might want to try looking into the addon AnimAide: https://github.com/aresdevo/animaide

In the graph editor it has the "Anim Transform" tool which "freezes time, so any transformation you do to an animated object or armature affects the entire animation equally".

Comment: Great addon, thanks! Lots of useful functionality in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the value of the key frames you can box select them all in the graph editor and move them all up or down until you get your desired effect.